# Retrofit and Moshi: parsing variable name objects

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, moshi

I'm using Retrofit 2 and Moshi to read and parse JSON from an endpoint.  My retrofit instance is defined like so:

```
val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl("https://myendpoint.com")
       .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
       .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
       .build()
```

And I'm using the Kotlin data class to store the information in a model:

```
@GET("data/getlist")
fun getData(): Single<Data>
```

Data class:

```
data class Data(val Response : String,
            val Message : String,
            val BaseImageUrl : String)
```

Now, because the JSON is formatted like so, the JSON is parsed and the model is populated just fine:

```
{
    "Response": "Success",
    "Message": "Api successfully returned",
    "BaseImageUrl": "https://www.endpoint.com/image/xxx.jpg",
}
```

This is because the objects map 1:1 with the model. So in the above example, the "Response" key mapped to the "Response" variable name in the Data class.

My question is this: what if the keys are all variable? How can you represent this in the Kotlin data class?

Sample JSON file to be parsed:

```
{
    "RandomX": "xxxxxx",
    "RandomY": "yyyyyy",
    "RandomZ": "zzzzzz",
}
```

Comment: If your keys could be anything, I would recommend making your model a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: That is, your Retrofit service call would return a `Single<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: Correct. So then how would I represent that in my data class?

    data class Data(val <???>: Map<String, String>)

Comment: Ah, I was thinking too complex. A custom data class isn't needed when it ends up being just a Map<String, String>. Thanks Eric! (I'd mark this as the accepted answer but I guess you can't do that on comments :/ )

Comment: You might have to do `@JvmSuppressWildcards` in Kotlin. Kotlin might try to make String into `? extends String`. Hopefully it doesn't, though, considering String is a final type.

Comment: @EricCochran What model are you referencing? The retrofit return or the structure of the model  for DataClass? Neither seems to work on 2.0 retrofit.

Answer (score 4):

As @eric-cochran pointed out, you don't really need a new data class to represent this. It'd end up being a Map, and you'd use it like so:

```
@GET("data/getlist")
fun getVariableData(): Single<Map<String, String>>
```